# Terra: Setting the right resolution when transforming data frame to SpatRaster

Tags: r, rasterization, terra

I have a data frame which cell sizes aren't regular due to some statistic analysis and filtering, but for presentation purposes I need to transform the data frame back to a SparRaster. I don't want to interpolate any values. As far as I understood, you need a empty SpatRaster which you can kind of fill with values in the end. The original resolution was 0.00267 degrees per pixel. So I tried:

```
library("terra")

df <- data.frame(
  x = c(-124.4794071, -124.4488517, -124.4340813, -124.3785262, -124.3674151),
  y = c(48.05501914, 48.06890792, 42.70384471, 43.32050684, 42.39551364),
  v = rnorm(5)
)


df_ext <- terra::ext(min(df$x), max(df$x), min(df$y), max(df$y))  # create an extent
df_r <- terra::rast(df_ext)  # convert to empty SpatRaster
terra::res(df_r) <- c(0.002666666667, 0.002666666667)  # set resolution to 0.00267 degrees which translates to 333 m
terra::crs(df_r) <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"  # set crs 


df_r <- terra::rasterize(as.matrix(df[, 1:2]), df_r, fun = mean, field = df$v)
```

It kind of works but the resolution is too fine so you can barely see the points. It seems that the resolution is somehow wrong. But if I set it to c(1, 1) it is too coarse. What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you set it somewhere between 0.00266667 and 1? Or are you expecting these points to lie exactly on a 0.00266667-spaced grid?

Comment: @Spacedman Yes I expect them to lie on a 0.00267 grid. The original data from which the data frame is derived from has this resolution.

Comment: But if you take the differences of, say, your x coordinates (`diff(df$x)`) they should be all integer multiples of 0.00267. But they're not.